# How to use Retrofit with suspend function that does not have a return value (Void)

Tags: android, retrofit2

When using suspend functions in Android, what is the correct way to handle Void responses?
For example, normally when making a call that does not return a values we do the following.

```
@Multipart
@POST("/v3/profile/combine")
fun combineProfile(@PartMap map: Map<String, @JvmSuppressWildcards RequestBody>): Call<Void>
```

How can I achieve the same result using suspend function?